# To fix 404 error & redirection loop error for wordpress subdirectory on Nginx

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I am fixing a 404 error for a wordpress site which use Nginx.

The site is under a subdirectory of the main site, e.g. the URL is www.site1.com/d1. The database are migrated from another wordpress site

There is a 404 error when clicking the posts and pages. Tried this solution at /etc/nginx/sites-available/[config file]:

```
location /d1{
try_files &uri &uri/ /d1/index.php?q=$uri&args;
}
```

It eliminates the 404 error when clicking the posts and pages, but the WP admin page of www.site1.com/d1/wp-admin has a redirection loop error.

How shall I fix it?

thanks!

Comment: Those `&uri` and `&uri/` should be `$uri` and `$uri/`. Can you get more details about the redirection loop? The `GET` and the `Location` response.

Comment: Hi Richard, I really didn't notice that! With the change, yes, it solves the problem! Thank you! I am going to amend it so everyone will know!

Comment: Thanks to @RichardSmith, this is the way:
location /d1{
try_files $uri $uri/ /d1/index.php?q=$uri&args;
}